# DOMDocument & XPath - HTML Tag of each Node

Tags: php, dom, xhtml, domdocument

Given the following PHP code using [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php):

```
$inputs = $xpath->query('//input | //select | //textarea', $form);

if ($inputs->length > 0)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $inputs->length; $j++)
    {
        $input = $inputs->item($j);

        $input->getAttribute('name'); // Returns the Attribute
        $input->getTag(); // How can I get the input, select or textarea tag?
    }
}
```

How can I know the tag name of each matched node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$inputs = $xpath->query('//input | //select | //textarea', $form);

// no need for "if ($inputs->length > 0) - the for loop won't run if it is 0
for ($j = 0; $j < $inputs->length; $j++)
{
  $input = $inputs->item($j);
  echo $input->nodeName;
}
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodename

P.S.: Apart from looking into the docs, a [`var_dump()`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) can be really helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I tried var_dump() and only a bunch of DOMDocument objects came up I also tried nodeValue but it wasn't quite it. I was looking for this at hours, thanks!