# PHP xml array parsing data

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

Hey all i have this type of XML i am trying to get data from. This is just a snip of the large XML code:

```
<entry>
  <id>http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[Letters/numbers here]group.calendar.google.com/public/basic/[Letters/numbers here]</id>
  <published>2013-08-01T13:40:24.000Z</published>
  <updated>2013-08-01T13:40:24.000Z</updated>
  <title type='html'>[Title Here]</title>
  <summary type='html'>When: Tue Sep 24, 2013 7am</summary>
  <content type='html'>When: Tue Sep 24, 2013 7am
        &lt;br /&gt;Event Status: confirmed
  </content>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=[Letters/numbers here]' title='alternate'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[Letters/numbers here]group.calendar.google.com/public/basic/[Letters/numbers here]'/>
  <author>
    <name>[email here]</name>
    <email>[email here]</email>
  </author>     
</entry>

   etc... etc....
```

Currently i can get both **published** and **updated** just fine by doing the following:

```
<?php
$url = strtolower($_GET['url']);
$doc = new DOMDocument(); 
$doc->load('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[number/letters here].calendar.google.com/public/basic');
$entries = $doc->getElementsByTagName("entry");

foreach ($entries as $entry) { 
  $tmpPublished = $entry->getElementsByTagName("published"); 
  $published = $tmpPublished->item(0)->nodeValue;

  $tmpUpdated = $entry->getElementsByTagName("updated"); 
  $updated = $tmpUpdated->item(0)->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

However i am unsure as to how to get the inner data from within the parent array - that being **link** in this case.

So i need to get

**link->href**

I would imagine it would be:

```
$tmpLink = $entry->getElementsByTagName("link"); 
$link = $tmpLink->item( 2 )->nodeValue;
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: have you thought about using xpath?  [relevant SO question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288940/domdocument-xpath-html-tag-of-each-node)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
$links = $doc->getElementsByTagName("link");

foreach ($links as $link) { 
  $href = $link->getAttribute("href");
}
```

if you want to get href... hope that I understood what you wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `simplexml_load_string` like following codes:

```
$entries = simplexml_load_string($string);

foreach ($entries as $entry) { 

    echo $entry->published;
    echo $entry->updated;  

    foreach($entry->link as $link)
    {
        echo $link->attributes()->type;
        echo $link->attributes()->rel;
    }
}
```